# SQL how do I display the sum of a column in the same colum on a gridview?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I'm working with a VB.Web application and what I'm trying is to get the the total amount of all the  column values at the end of same column in the output. For example I have a column with multiple prices and at the end of the column get the total of those prices. In my case I would like to do the same with D.ORIG_PRC.

Is there a way to do this by using this method of passing the values to the gridview?

Or am i better off using the the ASP control to output values to the gridview?

**Query**

```vb
Protected Sub ExecuteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExecuteButton.Click
    Dim StoreID As Integer
    Dim TransID As Integer
    Dim RgstID As Integer
    Dim dt As DataTable

    If Not Integer.TryParse(StoreIDTextbox.Text, StoreID) Then
            MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter both Store ID and Transaction ID.")
        Exit Sub

    End If

    If Not Integer.TryParse(TransactionIDTextbox.Text, TransID) Then
        MsgBox("Invalid input. Please enter both Store ID and Transaction ID.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    SQL.AddParam("@Str_ID", StoreID)
    SQL.AddParam("@Tran_ID", TransID)

    'Rgst_ID Validation
    If RegisterIDTextbox.Text.Length = 0 Then
        MsgBox("RgstID has no value")
        SQL.AddParam("@Rgst_ID", "")
    ElseIf RegisterIDTextbox.Text.Length > 0 Then
        MsgBox("RgstID has a value")
        RgstID = Integer.Parse(RegisterIDTextbox.Text)
        SQL.AddParam("@Rgst_ID", RgstID)
    End If

    Try
        dt = SQL.ExecQuery(" Select H.Emp_ID, H.Cust_ID, H.Rgst_ID, D.TRAN_LN_NUM AS Line#, D.DISC_CD AS Disc_CD, D.AUTH_EMP_ID AS Auth_Emp_ID, CAST(D.ORIG_PRC AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS Orig_Prc, CAST(D.DISC_AMT AS DECIMAL(19,2)) AS Disc_Amt, D.DISC_PCT AS Disc_Pct, D.GL_ACCT_ID AS GL_Acct_ID
                             From Transaction_Header H 
                             INNER Join LN_Detail L On (H.Str_ID = L.Str_ID And H.Rgst_ID = L.Rgst_ID And H.Tran_ID = L.Tran_ID)
                             INNER Join LN_Discount D ON (L.Str_ID = D.Str_ID And L.Rgst_ID = D.Rgst_ID And L.Tran_ID = D.Tran_ID And L.Tran_LN_Num = D.Tran_LN_Num)  
                             WHERE(H.Str_ID = @Str_ID)
                                And (H.Tran_ID = @Tran_ID)
                                And ((H.Rgst_ID = @Rgst_ID) Or (@Rgst_ID Is NULL Or @Rgst_ID = ''))")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    GridView1.DataSource = dt
    GridView1.DataBind()
    TimeLabel.Text = DateAndTime.Now
End Sub
```

**SQL Control**

```vb
Private ReadOnly ConStr As String = ""
Private DBCmd As SqlCommand

'Query Parameters
Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

'This generates a blank sqlclient class with the deafult connection string
Public Sub New()
End Sub

'Allow connection string override
Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
    ConStr = connectionString
End Sub

'Execute Query Sub
Public Function ExecQuery(query As String) As DataTable

    Dim DBDT = New DataTable
    Using DBCon As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            DBCmd As New SqlCommand(query, DBCon)
        Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))
        Params.Clear()
        DBCon.Open()
        DBDT.Load(DBCmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return DBDT
End Function

'Add Params
Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
    Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
    Params.Add(NewParam)
End Sub
```

Comment: Calcualte sum from datatable rows and add new row to the datatable and set total sum to the sum column.

Answer (score 0):

Per Fabio's comment:

```
'after you execquery()
Dim sum = dt.Compute("SUM([Orig_Prc])")
Dim r = dt.NewRow()
dt("Orig_Prc").Value = sum
dt.Rows.Add(r)
```

If any of your columns are `AllowDBNull = False`, then you'll have to put values for those too

---

You could also do this in the DB, by UNIONing on a SELECT that sums the columns you want. If you do that I would recommend you add a column for ordering and have the detail lines have `0` and the total line have `1` so that you can order by it and ensure the total appears at the bottom